# How is it possible that my int array isn't properly initialised

Tags: c

I am trying to return a pointer to an array of ints which are all dividers from a given number.
When I give 10 as an argument and run my program I notice that the method dividers_of(...) gives the proper output.
But unfortunately the second method called number_dividers(...) doesn't.
It appears as if some locations in the array haven't been set to 0 or a divider as shown by the output
'element 2009' for example.
What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* dividers_of(int number){
     int dividers [number];
     dividers[0]=1;
     int *ptr=dividers;
     int i;
     for(i=2;i<number;i++){
           if(number%i==0){
                  dividers[i]=i;
                  printf("deler : %i\n",dividers[i]);
           } else{
                  dividers[i]=0;
                  printf("niet- deler : %i\n",i);
           }
     }
     return ptr;
}

int number_dividers(int* ptr,int length){
    int * runner = ptr;
    int number_dividers ;
    while(runner!=ptr+length){
                    printf("element %i\n",*runner);
                        if(*runner!=0){
                                      number_dividers++;
                        }
                 runner++;
                 }
    return number_dividers;
}
```

Output:

deler : 2
niet- deler : 3

niet- deler : 4

deler : 5

niet- deler : 6

niet- deler : 7

niet- deler : 8

niet- deler : 9

element 1

element 2009

element 2008

element 0

element 0

element 1638

element 23

element 1

element 2293

element 0

Comment: BTW `int number_dividers ;` is not initialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't that the array isn't initialized, it's that it's a local variable inside a function and goes out of scope once that function returns.

Having and using a pointer to a local variable in another function results in [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

There are basically only two solutions available:

1. Dynamically allocate the memory in the function, and return it; Or
2. Define the array in the calling function, and pass it as an argument to the function that needs it.

Comment: But what if I assign that ptr ,which is returned by the method, to another ptr? Will it still show undefined behaviour if I assign that new pointer to the second method?

Comment: @BURNS If you make `ptr` point to the local array, and return it, the memory `ptr` points to will still go out of scope.

Comment: If the memory is dynamically allocated that the local variable will continue to exist?

Comment: @BURNS If you allocate dynamically with e.g. `malloc`, that memory is allocated to the whole process and you can pass around the pointer as you wish. The memory will be valid until you `free` it.